# Don't want the document structure to be created while parsing through JSOUP

Tags: javascript, html, parsing, jakarta-ee, jsoup

I am using a Jsoup API to parse a part of HTML using Jsoup.parse() method. However, while parsing it adds the document structure to the HTML content.

For Example:

```
<p><a href="some link">some link data</a> Some paragraph content</p>
```

Becomes

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<p><a href="some link">some link data</a> Some paragraph content</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't want the document structure after parsing (I don't want the html, head, body tags). Is there any way to do it?
Thanks in advance.

**SOLUTION**

I have use the body() and html() method of the Document

```
Document storyBodyDoc;
storyBodyDoc = Jsoup.parse(body);
storyBodyDoc.body().html()
```

Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could select the children of the body-element:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse("<p><a href=\"some link\">some link data</a> Some paragraph content</p>");
Elements content = doc.body().children();
```